# Qt WebEngine Spotify Playback codec error (mp4a)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, spotify, codec

I can load the webplayer just fine I have set the path for widevinecdm. But when I try to play any song on spotify,

```py
import sys
import os

from PySide2.Qt import *
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://open.spotify.com/"))
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error:

```
js: Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'addSourceBuffer' on 'MediaSource': The type provided ('audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"') is unsupported.
```

However, Youtube works fine.

How can I add `mp4a` codec into the webengine? Chromium can play spotify too.

Is there a flag I can set? I couldn't find if there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that your build of WebEngine is not including that codec. WebEngine can include/exclude proprietary codecs at build-time with the -webengine-proprietary-codecs. According to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs:

> Qt WebEngine supports the MPEG-4 Part 14 (MP4) file format only if the
> required proprietary audio and video codecs, such as H.264 and MPEG
> layer-3 (MP3), have been enabled.

So you may try to rebuild WebEngine with that option and then rebuild pyqtwebengine with the new Qt build.

Comment: you mean we should install qt from source? I use online installer. he uses python how could he add  codecs at build-time ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know for certain if the build from the installer includes proprietary codecs or not. You should rebuild QtWebEngine with the new flag and then rebuild the python bindings.

Comment: I installed with `pip` and it is not very apparent to me how I should build from source because I get a million dependency issues. I will try though later.